# Creating a Map for Term Frequency with Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

Alright so I am trying to make a `Map <String, Integer>` whose key is the word and the value is the frequency. Then using that I want to make a `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>` such that the key is the document title and the value is the Map with the term frequencies for the document. Here is my method:

```
private Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>> findTFs(Set<String> terms)
        throws IOException {
    // get an iterator for all the terms (words)
    TermsEnum termEnum = MultiFields.getTerms(reader, "content").iterator(
            null);
    //main map
    tf = new HashMap<Integer, Map<String, Integer>>();


    while (termEnum.next() != null) {
        //the parameter "terms" is just the 50 top words of the all documents
        if (terms.contains(termEnum.term().utf8ToString())) {
            //Document enumerator
            DocsEnum docEnum = MultiFields.getTermDocsEnum(reader,
                    MultiFields.getLiveDocs(reader), "content",
                    termEnum.term());
            int doc = DocsEnum.NO_MORE_DOCS;
            int count = 0;
            while ((doc = docEnum.nextDoc()) != DocsEnum.NO_MORE_DOCS) {
                System.out.println(docEnum.docID() + ": "
                        //document title 
                        + reader.document(docEnum.docID()).get("title")
                        //word
                        + ": " + termEnum.term().utf8ToString() + ": "
                        //frequency
                        + docEnum.freq());
            }
        }
    }
    return tf
}
```

My problem is that the loops are set up such that they move to the next document for each word and I have been struggling with making a single map for each document. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you add more documentation to the code so that it can be easily read? Thank you.

Comment: Added some comments thanks!

Comment: How about if you switch the outer while loop with the inner while loop?  Your control loop (the outer loop) should be the one that loops through the documents, and for each document you loop through the terms (that's the inner loop) to find out the frequency of each of those terms in the document.  When you don't have any more terms to try, you move on to the next document and you do the same thing again, until you're out of documents.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but every time I tried swapping the loops it never worked

Comment: I could see that when you're trying to create an instance of the document `docEnum`, you're using `termEnum`.  Is this why it's not working when you swap loops?

Comment: Exactly it gets all messed up when I try to flip the loop because I'm using termEnum as a parameter

Comment: Has the answer I posted worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Since your document instance depends on the term, you should probably add the document to the main map, with the inner terms frequency map.  When you move on to the next term, you might get a different document, which you would again add to the main map, or you might get a document that has been already added to the main map, in which case you would first check the main map if it contains that document, and if it does, you simply grab the inner terms frequency map to update it.

Here is some pseudo-code for the inner loop to illustrate:

```
while ((doc = docEnum.nextDoc()) != DocsEnum.NO_MORE_DOCS) {
    // Get document title, which is used as a key in the main map
    String docTitle = reader.document(docEnum.docID()).get("title");

    Map docTermFreq = null;

    // If document title already exists in main map
    if (tf.containsKey(docTitle)) {
        // Get the document term frequency map
        docTermFreq = tf.get(docTitle);
    } else {
        // Create one
        docTermFreq = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        // Put it in the main map
        tf.put(docTitle, docTermFreq);
    }

    docTermFreq.put(term, docEnum.freq());
}
```

The outer loop should remain the same.  At the end, you just return `tf`.  By the way, you need to change the method signature to return `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>` and not `Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>>`